# Complex Nginx Vhost Config

Tags: nginx, configuration, virtualhost

I tried whole day to make an nginx vhost config to acomplish my needs but i make it wrong all the time.
Here is what i need to do.

I have a server in which i stream Movies & Live Streams. The Movies & Streams are being restreamed from a .php file . Everything is fine with this. These 2 files are stream_live.php and stream_movies.php

I want to use different fastcgi_ settings depending on the type value i will select. For example for livestreams you can select to be in mpegts or hls. I want this as a parameter in PHP File. Now i will give examples in order to understand it better.

I want each time a user requests like this:

```
http://domain.com/live/username/password/1.live?type=hls
```

to be redirected in the file stream_live.php with parameteres username,password,id and type (1 = id here). How i can do that?

And for the movies i want a similar one like

```
http://domain.com/movies/username/password/1.movie
```

to be redirected in the file stream_movies with parameterers Username/Password/ID (1 = ID)

One small note! As i said above i want to use different settings if you are requesting movies or live streams.

So for **movies** i want to use

- **fastcgi_buffering off;**

For Live Streams i want to use

- **fastcgi_buffering on;** ***EXCEPT*** in **type=hls** which i want it **fastcgi_buffering off;**

Sorry that i'm requesting the whole nginx config but i tried whole day to make it and i couldn't. :(

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to control just the `fastcgi_buffering` setting based on the type parameter? Read the [fine manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering) and notice this part:

> Buffering can also be enabled or disabled by passing “yes” or “no” in
>   the “X-Accel-Buffering” response header field. This capability can be
>   disabled using the [fastcgi_ignore_headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_ignore_headers) directive.

So, to simplify this, use a simple nginx configuration for routing:

```
location /movies/ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/stream_movies.php;
}
location /live/ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/stream_live.php;
}
```

... and in PHP you should send the `X-Accel-Buffering: no` header field to disable buffering. For plain PHP you could use something like:

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'type') == 'hls') {
    // buffering is on by default, disable it for HLS
    header('X-Accel-Bufferring: no');
}
```

Remember that the default value for `fastcgi_buffering` is `on`. Adjust the logic above to your needs.

Comment: Thank you. omg. I didn't know that :/. And one last question. How do i pass the parameters such as username/password/id ?  I need the rewrite module right?

Comment: @user3393046 You could do that at nginx level using rewrite, but you could also make PHP parse the URL.